# Laravel 5.5 Api Registration issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to get this api up and running and keep on experiencing this error when I test in Postman.

```
1. api.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors']], function () {
     Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');
});

2. RegisterController 
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}}
```

3. Postman configuration set to Post, the body is set to raw and JSON(application/json) Below is the postman json code.

   {
        "name": "Walter White", 
        "email": "wwhite@someemaildomain.net",
      "password": "testpassword"
      }

Below is the error
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in file C:\xampp\examplestuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix your registration you should change your route definition to:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors']], function () {
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

I assume your `RegisterController` is using the trait `RegistersUsers`. This trait is providing the `register` method, which is using the `RegisterController::create` method to create the new user itself.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Request to your create function like:

```
protected function create(Request $request){...
```

and access your data like this:

```
$request->name
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to do validation also plz check below answer

```
 protected function create(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $validator =  Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $message){
                $messages[] = $message[0];
        }
        $messages = $messages;
        $message = implode(',',$messages);
        $response = $messages;

        return $response;

    }else{

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

}
```